# Saving Stream to a file

Tags: wcf, stream, arrays, filestream

I'm writing a WCF Service to Upload file using REST.

But my probleme come from this code :

```
    public void UploadFile(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
    {
        FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream("C:\\FileUpload\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

        byte[] bytearray = new byte[fileStream.Length];

        int bytesRead = 0;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        do
        {
            bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > 0);


        fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
        fileToupload.Close();
        fileToupload.Dispose();
    }
```

In this case, I was not able to get the fileStream.Length,  and I had a NotSupportedException !

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
Message=Specified method is not supported.
Source=System.ServiceModel
StackTrace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.get_Length()
   at RestServiceTraining.Upload.UploadFile(Stream fileStream, String fileName) in D:\Dropbox\Stuff\RestServiceTraining\RestServiceTraining\Upload.cs:line 37
   at SyncInvokeUploadFile(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

Do you have any solution for this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read the size of the stream because its unknown (it even might be endless).
You have to read all bytes until the Readc-call return no more data:

```
int count;
while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
{
    ....
}
```

See [this blog entry](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html) for an extensive sample on streaming.

Comment: Thank you Jan.
I tried the code in the blog, but in had some error :

System.IO.IOException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\FileUpload\radio.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Its good it work, I just forget to remove old code that open the same file before.
But I stil have another probleme when I try to upload some file i had : "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." as a repense from the service hadled by the HttpRequest tha I used to call the operation.

Comment: 400 is a very generic error. Maybe you find more info in the event log or in the IIS logs. A quick google search showed up this promising link: http://talentedmonkeys.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/wcf-400-bad-request-while-streaming-large-files-through-iis/